# Undefined Behaviour in C-Codeforces

Tags: c

this is a code written by me where i have to first take the sum of all negative odd numbers and positive integer numbers and add them together.As an example:
if n=5:

```
evn = 2 + 4 = 6

odd = -1 -3 - 5 = -9

result= 6 + (-9) = -3(ans)
```

This code is successfully working in my Codeblocks Ide,but when it shows a garbage value in Codeforces compiler.I've tried my best to figure it out,Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Also please tell me how do i find out UB ?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{   
 long long int n;
 scanf("%lld",&n);

 long long int evn,odd;

 if(n%2==0) //Im currently facing problem in this case.I got the expected output in codeblocksIDE
   {
     evn=n/2;
     long long int sum_pos = (4+(evn-1)*2)*evn/2;
     long long int sum_neg = (-2+(evn-1)*-2)*evn/2;
     long long int ans = sum_pos+sum_neg;
     printf("%lld",ans);
   }
else
 {
   evn = n/2;
   odd = evn+1;
   long long int sum_pos = (4+(evn-1)*2)*evn/2;
   long long int sum_neg = (-2+(odd-1)*-2)*odd/2;
   long long int ans = sum_pos+sum_neg;
  printf("%lld",ans);
 }
}


 Test: #16, time: 15 ms., memory: 4 KB, exit code: 0, checker exit code: 1, verdict: WRONG_ANSWER
 Input
 208170109961052

 Output
 -9223267951799795282

 Answer
 104085054980526
 Checker Log
 wrong answer 1st numbers differ - expected: '104085054980526', found: '-9223267951799795282'
```

Comment: The input is a 15 digit number. And `sum_pos` is roughly the square of that number. So `sum_pos` is about a 30 digit number. Unless you are running the code on a 128-bit processor, a 30 digit number is way too big for a `long long int`. It would be much easier just to realize that `2-1=1`, `4-3=1` , etc.